# How to use variable from node server into another javascript file

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Hello I'm new to node js, and came across using it while making an rtc project where I have to make calls, I use rtcmulticonnection library which has server.js and index.html

In index.html I have some data I want to push into the mysql database, so I use this code in server.js:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connectionsql = mysql.createConnection({
host: 'localhost',
       user: 'root',
       password: '',
       database: 'test'
});
connectionsql.connect((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
});
```

The above code is for connection to mysql in server.js so now I have some data in index.html (coming different each time).. I want to push into the database, how can i send that to server.js file and make a commit? i cannot use connectionsql into the script tag in index.html(script tag) file so can create a query like this:

```
const call = { room_id: caller_id, callee_id: callee_id };
connectionsql.query('INSERT INTO chat_calls SET ?', call, (err, res) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('Last insert ID:', res.insertId);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect to the `SQL` server directly from client side.

I don't know much about your server set up, but probably the way to go would be to set up an API endpoint on your server that the client side can post data to. Then, your server can insert the data it received from the client into the DB.

**EDIT**

A very common approach is to use an `express` server:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express

Follow the guide setting up your `express` server, and then register an endpoint for your client to post to.

There are many guides on the internet that can help you set it all up. If you run into trouble, I would suggest creating separate questions on SO for that.

Any further help would be beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate in details? How can i achieve so. I will be very thankful and sorry for trouble.

Comment: I added more details to the post @KaleemQasim

Comment: tysm, i'm looking into it.

Comment: Great, if it helps consider marking this answer as solved :)